# why is this VRP problem taking so long to solve with the AUTOMATIC first solution strategy?

Tags: or-tools

I've modified the data in https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw to my specific problem - see below.

If I'm trying with `FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC` or `FirstSolutionStrategy.AUTOMATIC`, it takes 42 seconds to solve this tiny problem!

If I'm changing to `FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_MOST_CONSTRAINED_ARC` it solves within 3ms.

Why is the solver so sensitive to this setting? Is there some mode in which the solver tries all strategies in parallel and selects the fastest or the best one?

```
def create_data_model():
  """Stores the data for the problem."""
  data = {}
  data['time_matrix'] = [
                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 73, 104, 113, 117, 99999],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 84, 99999, 122, 125, 99999],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 97, 75, 122, 125, 99999],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 61, 109, 114, 103],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 47, 99999, 83, 89, 77],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99, 92],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 88, 94],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 42, 64],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 51],
                       [1000, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999]]
  data['time_windows'] = [(0, 10000), (435, 450), (450, 465), (450, 465), (475, 490), (480, 495), (540, 555), (540, 555), (600, 615), (720, 735), (810, 825)]
  data['num_vehicles'] = 5
  data['depot'] = 0
  return data
```

also changed the time dimension:

```
routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        10000,  # allow waiting time
        10000,  # maximum time per vehicle
        True,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time)
```

Comment: because all these first solution heuristics are very sensitive to the nature of the problem, especially if finding a feasible solution is hard. These are really heuristics.

Comment: And you distance matrix very sparse. There are not that many arcs below the max time per vehicle. It becomes easy to trick the heuristics and makes finding the first solution hard.